# CSS Media Queries - where should they be defined?

Tags: css, media-queries

Is there a preference to where CSS media queries are defined?  I.e. should I call them from my html like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 350px)" href="../assets/css/350.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 768px)" href="../assets/css/768.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 992px)" href="../assets/css/992.css" />
```

Or should I maintain one CSS file and define the media queries there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever works best for you, really.

Personally I prefer defining them inside my main CSS file, alongside the rules that they affect. For example:

```
#someElement {font-size:24pt;}
@media all and (min-width:350px) {
    #someElement {font-size:12pt}
}
```

This keeps them close together so I don't lose track of them. It also means fewer HTTP requests.

Comment: How do you handle pre IE8?  Can you still do that with a conditional statement in the main HTML (<!--[if lt IE 9 & !IEMobile]>)

Comment: You could, but I'm kind of the opinion that if people actively hinder themselves by not letting Windows Update upgrade their browser, then why should I bother pandering to them?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would go for everything in a single file. You could (or should) manage the size and structure of your code by using a css preprocessor like less or sass. This way you can develop in multiple files, and combine / minimize them before you upload them to your webserver.

The main reason to use a single file is speed. Usually an extra request takes a lot longer then downloading a few extra kilobytes. It is also what is advised by the 'big ones' like Yahoo and Google...